# how to create dynamic query

Tags: apex, query, sobject, dynamic-soql

```
List<Opportunity> opps = [
        SELECT  Id
                ,Name
                ,Amount
                ,CloseDate
                ,Stagename
                ,Near_to_Close_Date__c
        FROM    Opportunity
        WHERE Stagename Not In ('Closed Lost', 'Closed Won')];
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: This query does not need to be dynamic, and most likely shouldn't be. If you have a specific objective for using Dynamic SOQL, you should edit your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

I see you're new there, you can use the official documentation [there](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) ;

This may be what you're looking for ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use below equivalent dynamic soql.

```
List<Opportunity> opps = Database.query( 'SELECT Id,Name,Amount,CloseDate,Stagename,Near_to_Close_Date__c '+
                               +'FROM Opportunity '+
                               +'WHERE Stagename Not In (\'Closed Lost\', \'Closed Won\')');
```

More on [Dynamic soql](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm).

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm)

OR

`String queryString = 'SELECT  Id,Name,Amount,CloseDate,Stagename,Near_to_Close_Date__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Stagename Not In (\'Closed Lost\', \'Closed Won\')';
List<Opportunity> opps = Database.query(queryString);`

Comment: Apex does not allow newlines in string literals.